# Curious to know step by step Process of for loop which involves let and var

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, var, let

I have 2 simple code snippet about for loop involving let and var separately.
First code which has a variable declared with let

```
 for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
       setTimeout(function() {
          console.log(i);
       }, 1000);
    }
```

so it will show o/p like this

```
0123456789
```

but if I replace let with var like this

```
 for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
       setTimeout(function() {
          console.log(i);
       }, 1000);
    }
```

```
it will print 10 for ten times.
```

I know it is something related to function level scope and block-level scope, but want to clearly understand step by step process of execution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why you are only printing `9` is that the callback function is executed after the loop is done. Which means that `i` is 9.

You can:

If you are trying to print 1 - 10 after 1 sec, you can loop in the callback function. Like:

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {       //Put the loop inside the setTimeout db function.
    console.log(i);
  }
}, 1000);
```

If you are trying to print every one sec, you can pass the `i` as the 3rd parameter on `setTimeout`

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  setTimeout(function(o) {           //Receive it on variale o
    console.log(o);
  }, 1000 * i, i);                   //Pass the i as third parameter
}
```

Doc: [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout)